# grep regex not returning result when regex stored in shellscript variable

Tags: regex, bash, shell, unix, grep

Let's say my Helloworld.txt contains

`function( '100');`

Now I want to search for any occurence of `'100'` after `(` which may have space in between. Now, with this UNIX command:

**Case-I:**

`grep "[(][ ]*'100'"  Helloworld.txt`

I get correct match found in Helloworld.txt.

But when I write a simple shellscript:

**Case-II:**

```
Key="100"
Key="\"[(][ ]*'$Key'\"" 
echo $Key
grep $Key Helloworld.txt
```

It correctly prints: `"[(][ ]*'100'"`

But, It doesn't return the match found in Helloworld.txt

Comment: Why add `\"`? Use `Key="[(][ ]*'$Key'" `

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I am enclosing with doublequotes because when I am grepping independently as shown in Case-I, I have double quotes around.

I just tested, Removing `\"` also didn't help. No matches found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating things a bit. Your original command can be written like this:

```
grep "( *'100'" Helloworld.txt
```

And if you want the number `100` to come from a variable, then use this:

```
grep "( *'$key'" Helloworld.txt
```

If you want to store the whole regular expression in a variable, then that would be:

```
regex="( *'$key'"
grep "$regex" Helloworld.txt
```

Note that syntactic quotes (like the ones around a string literal, or a variable) are not interchangeable with quotes inside strings. By this I mean that the following two things are **not equivalent**:

```
regex="( *'$key'" # good
grep "$regex"

regex="\"( *'$key'\"" # bad
grep $regex
```

---

Below is a test showing all of the options working:

```
$ cat file
function( '100');
$ grep "( *'100'" file
function( '100');
$ key=100
$ grep "( *'$key'" file
function( '100');
$ regex="( *'$key'"
$ grep "$regex" file
function( '100');
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to show each of the options working.